# How to pass a variable from one function to another function jquery

Tags: javascript

hello I would like my delivery variable created in the first function to be used in the second function

```
$('input[name="choix_livraison"]').on('click', function() {
      var livraison = $(this).attr('data-nom')
      
      console.log("verification si variable passe",livraison)

 });
 
        $("#cb_Nom").keyup(function() {
             console.log("verification si variable passe",livraison)
    
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var livrasion;

$('input[name="choix_livraison"]').on('click', function() {
    livraison = $(this).attr('data-nom')
      
    console.log("verification si variable passe",livraison)
});

$("#cb_Nom").keyup(function() {
    console.log("verification si variable passe",livraison)   
});
```

You can declare it as a global variable and since JQuery runs on the client side you don't have to worry about it being over written by other users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Unless I'm mistaken and in my case it doesn't work

I explain to you

In my form I capture a radio button in real time which is livraison

then in my second function I retrieve in real time an input nom

Comment: @jules if you click on an radio button and then type in the input field the 2 console logs will be the same.

Comment: I give you my example
you must first choose a delivery method before entering the name
https://codepen.io/flexi2202/pen/XWBwEmz

Comment: @jules ok so in your code you need to remove `var` from inside the radio button click

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just tried that but it doesn't work.
you can see the new version online

Comment: https://codepen.io/flexi2202/pen/XWBwEmz

Comment: @jules what's the desired output? because it seems to be working if you open the console.

Comment: when I enter text in the input I would like to see the console displayed which is in one of the conditions with the variable

Comment: when I click on a mode of sending the console with the variable is displayed well

when I enter a word in the input the console should again be displayed with the variable in the console

But for the moment it is not the case

Comment: I think this was missing in the first function

you can confirm

return livraison;